# angularjs - find element inside an element by id

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I would like to find an element inside an element based on id. How can I do it ? I know there is

```
 angular.element(document.queryselector("#id"));
```

it is used to select an element. But what about finding element inside an element in AngularJS ?

```
 <div id="outerID1">
    <div id="innerID">I am an inside element</div>
 </div>
 <div id="outerID2">
    <div id="innerID">I am an inside element</div>
 </div>
 <div id="outerID3">
    <div id="innerID">I am an inside element</div>
 </div>
```

To find this in jQuery,

```
var innerElement = $("#outerID2").find("#innerID");
```

Think like I am dynamivacally generating the multiple div's .Which has outer div id is different for all div's and inner id div's are same. In this scenario how can we solve this ?

Comment: As ids are unique then you can directly use the given id.

Comment: The ID must be unique. There is no need for finding an element by ID inside an element. For example angular.element(document.queryselector("#innerID")); should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

use `angular.element('#outerID2 #innerID')` if you have jQuery loaded in your app.
Otherwise, use `angular.element(document.querySelector('#outerID2 #innerID'))`

According to the doc from angular below, angular.element is a light version of jQuery which has a subset of functions that are commonly used in jQuery. For your purpose, it should be suffice to get element by their ids.

> angular.element
>   - function in module ng Wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element.
>
> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.
>
> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular
>   to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite
>   implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal
>   of having a very small footprint.
>
> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file.
>   You can also use the ngJq directive to specify that jqlite should be
>   used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple
>   versions exist on the page.

Comment: As you post, please add details for future readers to understand the change suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

You do have access to children(), contents(), and data() implementations, so you can usually find a way around it.

**EDITS**

You can try something like this

```
  var parentElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#'+parentId ) ).children();
  for(var i=0;i<parentElement.length;i++){
    if(parentElement[i].id === childId)
    {
      alert(parentElement[i].getAttribute('name'));
    }
  }
```

Also demo link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yf4gDSkX8O57YVaLdblt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do

```
 var now =  angular.element(element.getElementsByClassId("innerID"));
 alert(now);
```

Comment: NO suppose think like I am having outer id id different for all div and inner ID is unique means , How we can get that ?